# Suggestion for Implementing Scheduling algorithms in c

Tags: c, operating-system, scheduling

Given n processes with their burst times and arrival times, the task is to find average waiting time and average turn around time using scheduling algorithms like FCFS, Round Robin, Shortest remaining time, etc.,

I am very much confused in selecting a Data Structure to implement these algorithms. I implemented using a separate array for each attribute, but the thing it is tedious and we need to write a lot of statements in c. I am thinking of a linked list which each node represents the all attributes. Is it a efficient one. **Can you please suggest me a efficient data structure so that search and sorting will be easier**.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend that you read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Why you don't use a `struct` to model your processes? You could show some code to expose your attempts.

Comment: structure is also a good idea.

Comment: By the way, *don't* do sorting. Instead keep a priority queue (where the "priority" is anything you want) where you insert nodes in order. Then you don't need to sort. If the "priority" can change, then simply remove the node from the queue, and reinsert it. The next process to run will always be the "first" node in the queue.

Comment: For round-robin it's even easier since you don't need any sorting at all, just a plain queue where you add processes at the end and get from the start.

Comment: Yep, That's a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: A struct with double-linked pointers is a good choice. The operations of an OS kernel typically involve linking thread/process descriptors into and out of queues etc., so an efficient insert/remove is good design.  It's amazing how data piles up in such structs when designing your OS, and a LL is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a data structure to contain the "impossible to know in practice" information about each process (start time, burst time, etc), add a "process state" field (to keep track of "not started, started or stopped"), and add a single "next" field to the structure; then create an array of these structures and fill in the information.

Next create a general purpose function to find the "not started" process that has the earliest start time.

For round robin; find the "not started" process that has the earliest start time, set "current time = first process start time", and set the process' "next" field to point to itself so that you have a circular linked list of one entry, and change the state of the process from "not started" to "started". Then find out which event happens next (will another process start and get added to the circular linked list before a task switch happens?) and handle that event (while advancing your "current time").

For FCFS it's similar to round robin, except you don't bother having task switches until the currently running task stops (and could use a non-circular list instead of a circular list).

For shortest remaining time, it's the same as FCFS except that when a process is started you use "remaining time" to figure out where to insert it into the list.